# Worksheet code across multiple sheets

Tags: vba, excel, navigation

I have a navigation bar at the top of some of my worksheets and want to apply the navigation code across the whole workbook rather than having to paste the code in every worksheet. It works by clicking a cell which would then call a navigation macro. I have the following code (snippet) which is functional but there surely has to be a more efficient way of doing this rather than pasting in every sheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    'Navigation bar
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E2:I3")) Is Nothing Then
        Call goto_Introduction
    End If

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("J2:N3")) Is Nothing Then
        Call goto_OverviewInputs
    End If

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("O2:S3")) Is Nothing Then
        Call goto_PopulationSize
    End If
```

Apologies if this has been asked before, but haven't found any solutions thus far...

Comment: Wouldn't that be a good idea to use buttons for this task? Then you could define the procedures in a module and won't have these issues. I think using cell selection is not the best practice to do this. Therefore you would usually use buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could transfer the logic into a module:

```
'put this within a module
Option Explicit

Public Sub NavigationBar(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Parent.Range("E2:I3")) Is Nothing Then
        goto_Introduction 'note that the call statement is deprecated
                          'and not needed to call a procedure!
    End If

    If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Parent.Range("J2:N3")) Is Nothing Then
        goto_OverviewInputs
    End If

    If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Parent.Range("O2:S3")) Is Nothing Then
        goto_PopulationSize
    End If
End Sub
```

so you only need to insert a call to that logic into every worksheet

```
'put this within the worksheets you need it
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    NavigationBar Target
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, got it to work easily enough and will help tidy up my future coding! May I ask what the importance of 'Option Explicit' is?

Comment: `Option Explicit` forces you to declare **every** variable properly that you are going to use (for example `Dim i As Long`). That forces you to be strict, but prevents mis-typed variable names and therefore less hidden errors. Because now if you mis-type a variable name you will get notified that this variable is not declared. It is a very best practice to **always** use `Option Explicit`, and no reason to not use it. Even for beginners it makes life and debugging much easier. Note: If this answer helped you, please consider marking it as solution so others can see, that is was solved.